# VPS add repository error

Tags: linux, bitcoind

I would like to install Bitcoind under (VPS) linu system. I got a step by step tutorial how can i do this installation, but everytime when i tried to add repository i got the following error message on console "sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found"

commands for installation

- sudo aptitude install python-software-properties
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
- sudo aptitude update
- sudo aptitude install bitcoind
- mkdir ~/.bitcoin/

Answer (score 2):

These commands are appropriate for an Ubuntu distribution and not CentOS.

The analogous commands that CentOS uses are `yum install` / `yum update`, etc.

Comment: Well i don't know but when i tried to call yum commands i got this error -bash: yum: command not found, i installed phpmyadmin via command "sudo apt-get install ..." maybe on VPS is another operating system than CentOs.( I am sorry, i have to change the title of this question).